# High CPU usage when rendering DVD movie in Pinnacle

Tags: cpu, speed

I'm running Windows 7 Quad Core 4100. When rendering a DVD movie in Pinnacle 16 I get a pop up message of High CPU usage.  According to Task Manager it's running in the high 90 percent and has stopped working at times.

How can I slow the CPU usage down?

Comment: When you say it stops working at times, do you mean the computer slows down, or crashes? Having high CPU usage while running video editing software is normal.

Comment: Why would you want rendering to take longer?!

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is expected and perfectly good for video rendering. If you have a multi core machine (and if Pinnacle is multi core aware), you can go to task manager, right click the process and set the affinity to only a few cores.

However, I would leave it at 100% if I was you - would you rather run the CPU at 50% and it take twice as long?

Personally, I would also check for antivirus and see if you can exclude Pinnacle's temporary folder and whatever folder it is saving the file to as that may make a big difference (and if it doesn't lower CPU, it could increase speed heavily).

Answer (score 0):

Check for other running programs and kill them. Make sure your computer has plenty of airflow, laptop assuming, and that the temperatures of your CPU cores aren't terribly high. [CoreTemp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) is a good means of doing that.

Comment: I have disabled all servises so nothing else is running and still the CPU runs in the high 90's percent

Comment: I see you're running desktop also. Is your computer well ventilated? Cleaned the fans and the heatsink recently?

Comment: @user193338: That's good. It means your software is taking full advantage of your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I did your suggestion - cleaned the CPU. The CPU was factory installed on the mother board but when I took it apart it was obvious to me that the Heat Paste was not adaquat or aplied very well.
  It now still runs in the mid to high 90% range and hits 100 quite a lot now that it didn't do before but it hasn't crashed my program since.
  I suspect that if that paste was not adaquat the CPU could have developed enough temp to shut down; just guessing.  Thank you.  Jay

Comment: Ohhhh, did you meen 90 **degrees**? Or processor utilization?